# Error resolving variables and left-side side assignments and figuring ++ tokens

Tags: java, token, java.util.scanner

I'm starting to get blind looking at my code and my brain is about to overheat. I'm new when it comes to programming.

public class RecyclingSystem {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

System.out.println("Please put in a valid bottle");


    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);



    while ( sc.nextInt() != -1) {

        if (sc.nextInt(char a) = getaBottle);
                int bottleAcount++;
    } else if { (sc.nextInt(char b) = getbBottle);
                int bottleBcount++;
    } else if { (sc.nextInt(char c) = getcBottle);
                int bottleCcount++;
    } else { throw new EmptyStackException(); 
        System.out.println("Bottle not recognized");
    }
    System.out.println("The total number of bottles is " + totalBottlecount);
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("The total amount returned is " + sumOfBottles );
    }
    sc.close();
}
```

}}

public class Bottle {

```
private static final double A_BOTTLE = 1.0;
/**
 * @return the aBottle
 */
public static double getaBottle() {
    return A_BOTTLE;
}
/**
 * @return the bBottle
 */
public static double getbBottle() {
    return B_BOTTLE;
}
/**
 * @return the cBottle
 */
public static double getcBottle() {
    return C_BOTTLE;
}
private static final double B_BOTTLE = 1.5;
private static final double C_BOTTLE = 3.0;
```

}

public class EmptyStackException extends Exception {

}

public class bottleCount {

```
int bottleAcount = 0;

int bottleBcount = 0;

int bottleCcount = 0; 

int totalBottleCount = bottleAcount + bottleBcount + bottleCcount;
```

}

I have seperate classes for the getbottle, totalBottlecount and bottlecount variables.

I want to make a user-input based recycling system simulator, if that makes any sense, with 3 different types of bottles, which are assigned different values, a total bottle count and the sum of the values of the 3 bottle types combined.

I get several compiler errors and I have spend HOURS trying to resolve them all, but every time I do, new errors occur and now I get a "coders-block".

I get asked to delete the ++ tokens, the compiler cannot resolve my variables and syntax errors. I would really appreciate some insight, since I'm only ~3weeks into java programming.

UPDATED: Compiler errors exact copy pasta

```
Multiple markers at this line
    - Syntax error, insert ")" to complete Expression
    - Duplicate method nextInt(char) in type RecyclingSystem
    - Syntax error, insert "}" to complete Block
    - Syntax error, insert "AssignmentOperator Expression" to complete Assignment
    - Return type for the method is missing
    - Syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens
    - The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable
    - Syntax error, insert "AssignmentOperator Expression" to complete Expression
    - The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable
    - Syntax error, insert ";" to complete BlockStatements
    - Syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens
    - Syntax error on token ")", { expected after this token
    - Syntax error, insert ";" to complete Statement
```

Comment: Show us the compiler errors, if you can

Comment: `int bottleCcount++;` is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

```
int bottleAcount++;
```

In java you need to declare the local variable like

`type` `name` = intial value;

then do any operation on that like increament or decrement.

In youe case declar the variable before while loop with `zero` as intial value like

```
int  bottleAcount = 0;
```

then inside while increament it by 1, like `bottleAcount++;`

or

```
bottleAcount += 1;
```

Comment: Alright thats noted, i forgot to edit that before i posted this. I already declared bottleAcount in another class.

Comment: can you show that piece of code, if you decalre it in another class method, then please have a instance of that class and call the method which will do increament by 1 for like, before while A a= new A(); a.increamentByOne(); inside your while. you can't reffer to that variable directely here .

Comment: here I mean class A means where you have your variable defined, as well please remeber in your if statment the way you are doing is wrong, you should comapre not perform assignment, you should use == not =, in java = is assignment and == is for equal condtion checking for primitives

Answer (score 0):

So... If this is all the code there are many problems and what can I recommend in the beginning - go back to some basic Java programming course.

Let's look at one of the first lines:

`if (sc.nextInt(char a) = getaBottle);`

- Firstly, it's a condition, and you are **assigning** the value of a getaBottle to the `sc.nextInt(char a)`.
- Secondly, `nextInt(char a)` looks like method declaring, not like a method call.
- Thirdly, getaBottle is never declared before
- Fourthly, you have a `getaBottle()` method in a `Bottle` class, which you probably want to use instead of `getaBottle` which is (should) be a variable

...etc., etc.

This code is not even valid Java code. It's hard to help you somehow in that problem, you just need to learn a bit more, which I encourage you to do.

Good luck and in case of any *specific* question - come and ask!

Comment: I just started majoring computer science at a Danish university, and this is (part of) a beginners mandatory assignment. So this feels like rock bottom right now, which I heard its supposed to. Just having a hard time, but I'm most likely gonna reply again when i improve this code a bit.

Comment: @Alexandermeyeer just continue with some course, don't worry that now you have so much compiler errors. Probably you started doing coding without some solid basics.
Hope my answer helped you somehow, anyway - good luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
else if { (sc.nextInt(char b) = getbBottle);
                int bottleBcount++;
    }
```

Syntax is totally wrong for if.Also condition is checked using `==` not `=`  It should be :

```
else if (sc.nextInt(char b) == getbBottle);
                int bottleBcount++;
```

Also you cant do `int bottleBcount++`. Its meaningless. Since you already declared `bottleBcount` in another class, you have to access it using the object of that class. Before that change the declaration in the class from `int bottleAcount = 0;` to `public int bottleAcount = 0;` . Do this for all bottles.
Now you can use it as :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

System.out.println("Please put in a valid bottle");

     bottleCount counter = new bottleCount();
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);



    while ( sc.nextInt() != -1) {

        if (sc.nextInt(char a) == getaBottle);
                counter.bottleAcount++;
    } else if (sc.nextInt(char b) == getbBottle);
                counter.bottleBcount++;
    else if (sc.nextInt(char c) == getcBottle);
                counter.bottleCcount++;
     else { throw new EmptyStackException(); 
        System.out.println("Bottle not recognized");
    }
    System.out.println("The total number of bottles is " + totalBottlecount);
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("The total amount returned is " + sumOfBottles );
    }
    sc.close();
}
```

Also the statement `int totalBottleCount = bottleAcount + bottleBcount + bottleCcount;` doesnt make sense. It won't work as you wanted it to. You need to write a function to do this addition and then call it. Or if you want this to happen just once ( which I doubt) , you can put it in a constructor.

I suggest you brush up on `class` and variable declaration concepts before proceeding

Answer (score 0):

You just have problem in this:

```
else { 
    throw new EmptyStackException(); 
    System.out.println("Bottle not recognized");
}
```

Check the proper syntax and error will be resolved.